# Django load script from another app into an html file

Tags: python, django, boto3

I'm having trouble using a script from a file in App1 in a page in app2.
My project structure looks like this:
[image]

I want to use the following file in home/static/scripts/scripts.py
Inside an html file in project/templates/project/s3.html

My scripts.py file looks like this:

```
import boto3

def listS3():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
        print(bucket.name)
```

My s3.html file looks like this:

```
{% include "home/_header.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<div class="s3">

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

To be frank I'm not even sure how to load that script and how to call it afterwards as this is my first project in django. 
Do I use:

```
{% load script.py %}
```

Or something like that?
How do I later call function listS3 in the html file?
Like this?

```
{% listS3() %}
```

? I appreciate your help.

Comment: You're thinking along completely the wrong lines. Anything like this needs to be done in the view.

Comment: But note that that script will not do anything useful anyway, as all it does is print to the console.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Could you point me in the right direction then? A link perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not understand the basic Model-View-Template pattern structure of Django.

It might be a good idea to re-study the basic design of Django and take a look at the code.

This is Django's Official Tutorial
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

Python script methods can not be called directly from within a Django template. In Django, you need to pass  variables, objects, and Methods to be used in the Template in the form of "Context" in "View".

This is Django's official tutorial for that part.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will do that first.